# output or write to a xml file?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xmlwriter

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<allproperty></allproperty>');

while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
   if (count($line) < 4) continue; // skip lines that aren't full

   $node = $xml->addChild('aproperty');
   $node->addChild('postcode', $line[0]);
   $node->addChild('price', $line[1]);
   $node->addChild('imagefilename', $line[2]);
   $node->addChild('visits', $line[3]);
}

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

im using this script to convert text file into a xml file, but i want to output it to a file, how can i do this simpleXML, cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`file_put_contents`](http://fr.php.net/file_put_contents) function would do it. The function take a filename and some content and save it to the file.

So retaking your example you would just to replace the echo statement by `file_put_contents`.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<allproperty></allproperty>');
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
   if (count($line) < 4) continue; // skip lines that aren't full

   $node = $xml->addChild('aproperty');
   $node->addChild('postcode', $line[0]);
   $node->addChild('price', $line[1]);
   $node->addChild('imagefilename', $line[2]);
   $node->addChild('visits', $line[3]);
}

file_put_contents('data_out.xml',$xml->saveXML());
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, you can use asXML() for that. I mean, it's [right there in the manual](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php), just read it and your life will get easier. *(I assume, perhaps asking StackOverflow for basic stuff is easier for some)*

Also, and this one is more circumstantial, you don't necessarily need to use `addChild()` for every child. If there is no child of that name, it can be assigned directly using the object property notation:

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<allproperty />');

while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
   if (count($line) < 4) continue; // skip lines that aren't full

   $node = $xml->addChild('aproperty');
   $node->postcode      = $line[0];
   $node->price         = $line[1];
   $node->imagefilename = $line[2];
   $node->visits        = $line[3];
}

$xml->asXML('data.xml');
```

Comment: The problem with using  $xml->asXML('data.xml'); is when your xml is malformed for example if you are receiving xml from a remote Api  via curl and you try and save it.   It won't save and give you  error cannot use asXML on Boolean